# How long is stub zone NS servers timeout?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone

I could not find any documentation on how long is a stub zone timeout? i.e. DNS server bar.com with a stub zone foo.com and 2 NS servers in the stub zone: ns1.foo.com and ns2.foo.com

What is the timeout on bar.com to switch from ns1.foo to ns2.foo and then to root hints?
Is it configurable/traceable?

Comment: This question will be much easier to answer precisely [if you don't redact the domain names in question](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/6574/55514).

Comment: @MadHatter, domain names are actually irrelevant here, the question is very generic and applies only to timeout setting (or constant?) in Windows DNS stub zone -> nameservers. For example, a Linux DNS client timeout is controlled by a default value or the one specified in /etc/resolve.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instant/forever/undefined. It sounds like you're not configuring your [glue records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Circular_dependencies_and_glue_records) properly.

**Note:** The glue records generally only makes sense with subdomains. It looks like you are trying to do this with sibling domains. If that's the case you're better off updating your registrar's glue records and not maintaining a stub zone on nameservers that otherwise be uninvolved.

If you're delegating a zone to nameservers within it, you must have both the NS records for the zone in your stub zone **and** accurate A/AAAA records for the hosts that correspond to those NS records.

Comment: glue records are defined but its possible that one or both of the NS servers get offline or overloaded or (accidentally) blocked by a firewall etc etc. no?